# Convert vector<Point3f> to CvMat* in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion

I am using the C++ OpenCV interface but need to use a function that hasn't been reimplemented for the interface so uses the old convention (function is `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2` if it matters)

So I need to convert a `vector<Point3f>` to a `CvMat*` ...how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the result should be, but if I read the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) right, you can convert your type in a few steps:

First, create the new counterpart `Mat` to `CvMat*`:

```
std::vector<Point3f> myVec = ...;
//template<typename _Tp> explicit Mat(const vector<_Tp>& vec, bool copyData=false);
Mat m = Mat(myVec);
```

Then use `Mat`'s cast operator:

```
//operator CvMat() const;
CvMat cvm = static_cast<CvMat>(m);
```

and finally call your function

```
cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2(...,&cvm,...);
```

However, I've no experience with OpenMv, so I'm just citing the documentation. This may not reflect what you wanted it to do, in which case you may have to clarify your question.

Comment: Technically the correct answer, although I will use the above. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben: I would certainly suggest you do!

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps [cv::solvePnP()](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/79552)

`cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2` has been renamed to `solvePnP`.